# Trouble getting attribute of relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relation

I'm having a trouble with a relation in Laravel 5. the thing is that I have a table *User* and that user belongs to a *Group* for that, in the *User* model I have this:

```
public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Group');
}
```

The model *Group* have this attributes: name,unity,level, init_date. I also put there a default function to return a group as String, this is the code:

```
public function __toString(){
        return $this->name.' Unity '.$this->unity;
    }
```

So, the thing that in a view a have many users and for each of them I want to display the unity, name,date. When I call `$user->group` it returns me correctly the name and the unity in a String (because the _toString function) that means that he is really querying the group perfectly, but then, when I want to access a simple attribute as unity,date,or name with `$user->group->name` Laravel gives me this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I even tried `$user->group()->name` then I gets: Undefined property: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`

**Edited:**

The model User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password','estate','filial_id','perfil_id','rol','cat_teacher'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function filial(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Filial');
    }

    public function perfil(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Perfil','perfil_id');
    }

    public function grupo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Group','group_id','id');
    }
}
```

The model Group:

```
class Group extends Model {


protected $table = 'groups';

protected $fillable = ['name','unity','date'];

public function filiales() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Filial');
}

public function teacher(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\User','teacher_id');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\User');
}
}
```

Then, in the controller I made a `dd($users)` and there not appear the relations, appears other relations but not this one. In the view I want to print some of the attributes in a table, for that I have:

```
<td>{{$user->group}}</td>
<td>{{$user->group->unity}}</td>
```

The first line works perfectly, and I don´t know why.

Comment: There's not a `Group` with the `id` corresponding to the `group_id` of the model. To debug, try dumping `$user->group_id` and afterwards manually finding that Group with `Group::find($user->group_id)`.

Comment: Hi @Dencker ok. But in that case, why the `_toString` function returns me the name and unity correctly?

Comment: There's something in between that's wrong. The `__toString()` method can _only_ exist on an object (obviously), i.e. when you access `$user->group`, that should be an object. However, when chaining `->name` onto that, you're getting an error that you're trying to access a property of something that is not an object (which is basically impossible if casting it to a string really would return the correct result). Please provide your full example and (stripped) models to help troubleshooting.

Comment: @Dencker I edited man

Comment: Looks like you have a typo:        `return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Grupo','grupo_id','id');` - "Groupo", not "Group". Or is that just lost in translation?

Comment: @Dencker my mistake in translation

Comment: @Dencker Thanks man! I fixed, the thing is with the registers that doesn't have a group assigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're unable to return your `group`'s name is that `->group()` returns an instance of the query builder, and not an eloquent collection/object. Since a `user` belongs to a single `group`, modify your code in one of these two ways:

```
public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Group')->first();
}
```

And then access the group using one of the following methods:

```
$user = User::with("group")->where("id", "=", 1)->first();
$group = $user->group;
echo $group->name;

// OR

$user = User::where("id", "=", 1)->first();
$group = $user->group();
echo $group->name;
```

Or, leave the `group()` function as it is and access `->group()->first()` on your `$user` object:

```
$user = User::where("id", "=", 1)->first();
$group = $user->group()->first();
echo $group->name;
```

Any of the above methods should properly return your `group` object's name (or other attributes). Check the [Eloquent Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) for detailed explanations on how to access these objects.

Comment: sure man! I already did it but I had the same error, the thing is with the registers that doesn't have a group